# ¿Cómo remuevo el margen que trae Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hace mucho que no formateaba la PC y olvidé cómo quitaba esta línea de en medio.

Answer (score 0):

Selecciona el menú: **Herramientas / Opciones**

Luego: **Editor / Formato**

Seleccionar en **"Lenguaje" -> Todos los lenguajes**

En **"Margen derecho" poner 0**

De todos modos la línea está ahí para que no escribas demasiado, yo no la quitaría.

Saludos.

Comment: Otra cosa, cómo desactivo la opción que, cuando clickeo una variable, se marcan todas las que hay en el código?

Comment: Eso es otra pregunta, deberías plantearla a parte. Es una característica de ayuda  a la programación y no me plantee quitarla. Puedes votar / aceptar como válida mi respuesta si te sirvio.